# OpenGL: Why look down along -z axis in eye space?

Tags: opengl, rendering

I learned that, when we use perspective projection, we look down along -z axis in eye space, which means we set the points with negative z values in eye space at first, and then divide them by -z in perspective division converting the z values back to positive values.

But why bother? If we just draw the points in the first quadrant initially, there will be no such positive and negative conversions at all. If this is just a convention, why we use positive z values when we use orthographic projection? Now I'm reading a STL file, which saves the points in positives coordinates, should I still convert them into negative values and convert them back in prospective division?

Comment: This is historical, in modern GL you can use any convention you want since you control every step of vertex transformation from object-space to clip-space. But traditionally, the projection matrix flipped the Z-axis. Immediately following eye-space, everything (clip-space / NDC) is left-handed with the positive z-axis pointing forward in all popular graphics APIs (***this*** you have no say in and must conform to). I don't know what, if any, benefits GL's flipped z-axis ever offered though?

Comment: I'd point you here, this is as good an explanation as any: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/88776/112612 .

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Thanks, that passage explains it very well. But I think just swapping the x and y coordinates can also convert it from a right-hand space to a left-hand one. Maybe a swap will be simpler?

Answer (score 0):

How to simply change  x and y axis then? It's not a real thing that right hand and left hand coords, and row vector and col vector. You can change anything anytime by multiplying a matrix (usually view matrix) or by changing orders of arrangement of Matrix or one OpenGL range option.

There is a default setting as if OpenGL is a left handed coordinate like the default range, [Near, Far] is [0.0 to 1.0] not [1.0 to 0.0] However, a default is just a default we can change it as well. Changing x and y axis means many things but physically, you can't change it because it is nothing.

Comment: All you mean is that it is JUST a default setting? But I'm asking why.

Comment: Because it is an abstract, there is no reason.  You are asking why 100x (1/100) = 1 is same as 100/100 = 1. All things are about Linear Algebra. If you multiply your own perspective projection which make NDC [near,far] [-1,1], your question is wrong because now OpenGL is based on Left handed coord in eye space.